# Clustering standard errors glm() R

Tags: r, glm

I want to run a probit model using `glm()` function in R.

Say I have a`df` with dependent dummy variable `y` and independent variables `x1`, `x2`, and `x3`. I also have fixed effects variables, `year` and `company`. I run the glm model as follows:

```
# define model
model <- glm(y ~ x1 + x2 + x3 + year + company,
                    data = df,
                    family = binomial(link = "probit"))
# model summary
summary(model)

# cluster standard errors by year
library(sandwich)
cluster_se <- vcovCL(model, cluster = df$year)

# show results after standard errors clustered by year
coeftest(model, cluster_se)
```

The problems:

1. I want to measure a partial F-statistic from the model, which I can easily do as follows:

```
library(car)
car::linearHypothesis(model, c("x1= 0", "x2= 0"), test = "F")
```

However, this gives the F-statistic for the original model and not the clustered model. Can you please advise how can this be done?

2. I also want other statistics from the clustered model, such as Psuedo R-squared, AIC, and number of observations. How can I get these statistics from the clustered model? See below my approach to calculating pseudo R-squared (but this too only gives statistics from the original model, not the clustered).

```
# psuedo R-squared
with(summary(probit_model), 1 - deviance/null.deviance)
```

Would appreciate your help.